# How to edit htacess file to support file upload

Tags: php, .htaccess, file-upload, webserver

I have a sample image upload code written in php. An ios developer calls the web service. The file upload works well with One server but fails to upload in another server.

Checked the permissions, directory listing etc. Of all the above when trying to upload an image, Server throws 500 internal error.

I think there might be an issue with .htaccess

Can anyone guide me to edit the htaccess so that it supports image upload.

Thank you. 
While uploading via browser, the file upload works fine. It is not returning any errors

here is the error log
PHP Warning:  fopen(xml/) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/appsimon/public_html/api/import.php on line 271

Actually it worked on this server till last week. All of a sudden file upload failed

code in htaccess

```
#old php Handler
#deny from all 
#allow from ip address
```

Only these 3 commented lines
Error from the app console

```
    <Warning>: aResponse:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
 <html><head>
 <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
 </head><body>
 <h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
 <p>The server encountered an internal error or
 misconfiguration and was unable to complete
 your request.</p>
 <p>Please contact the server administrator,
  webmaster@appsimon.com and inform them of the time the error occurred,
 and anything you might have done that may have
 caused the error.</p>
 <p>More information about this error may be available
 in the server error log.</p>
 <p>Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error
 error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
 </body></html>
Feb  6 00:30:48 Varmas-iPhone SNMC[1944] <Warning>: -JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
     "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Unrecognised leading character\" UserInfo=0x541a40 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unrecognised leading character}"
 )
Feb  6 00:30:49 Varmas-iPhone SNMC[1944] <Warning>: fail
```

Comment: what is in your error log?

Comment: Show your htaccess, because error 500 can mean there is an error in your htaccess.

Comment: there is nothing in htaccess file everything is commented. Its a linux server

Comment: @John i updated my question with error log kindly go through it

Comment: nah, wont do, thats just a php warning, that wont trow a 500 (but it tels you that a directory does not exists, you might want to look at it). Maybe you can show what is in you htaccess file, and show the apache error logs.

Comment: if you delete the htaccess file from the server does the 500 error go away?

Comment: @Ronnie I dint dare to remove the htaccess file. Because i came to know it is essential.

Comment: just copy it locally, delete it from the server and see if it goes away..if it doesn't just put it back. Currently your htaccess does absolutely nothing if in fact what you posted is accurate

Comment: Unless I am missing something, the issue has nothing to do with .htaccess content. The warning message is pretty clear: `Warning: fopen(xml/) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/appsimon/public_html/api/import.php on line 271` So the problem is the upload script can't be found. Adjust the path, because it is not where the path indicates or it has a wrong name (import.php).

Comment: @faa that wouldn't cause a 500 error

Comment: @faa Ok if something wrong with the path, why does file uploaded from the browser succeeded.

Comment: @Rama Because you access the file in the browser with a URL: `http://mydomain.com/api/import.php` for example. The path in the error is a system path that is supposed to match the URL. Maybe it doesn't.

Comment: @faa ya you are right. good point. Let me recheck.

Comment: @Ronnie I tried deleting the .htaccess file but no success

Answer (score 0):

in your htaccess try adding these values and see what happens

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 100M
php_value max_execution_time 180
php_value max_input_time 180
```

adjust the values as needed

Comment: Please check my edited question for the response. Its same as earlier

Comment: The file i am sending is 50kb